# Attempt Upgrade from 4.7 to 5.48 and database upgrade fails

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, database

I'm new to CiviCRM and am working for a client who's 4.7.x CiviCRM has issues where I'm unable to access tabs and I get an error when switching to some tabs in the menu system, so I'm trying to upgrade.

I've got 5.48.0 uploaded via FTP to the server. I've tarred the old version in the same directory so it doesn't conflict and I have a backup. (I also have backups in the backups panel in Siteground, so good there).

I deleted the old version, unpacked the new version, and deleted the cache files as instructed. When I go to click for the database upgrade, it fails.

[image]

I also no longer see all my data tables on the main Dashboard page, either.

[image]

Should I change the version of PHP before I try to run the database upgrade function?

Answer (score 1):

You need at least php 7.2 to run civi 5.48. Even then it may be a big jump and if that doesn't work you may need to upgrade to intermediate versions in smaller jumps.

Comment: Thanks. The advice I've been getting in the CiviCRM chat forum is the same. Upgrade incrementally. The problem is, Siteground has removed PHP 7.2 from its servers, so we can only use 7.3.x and CiviCRM 7.4.31 may not run well on that version. Since I'm new to CiviCRM, I'm not sure where to find in the docs what versions of CiviCRM run on which version of php.

Comment: That's a good question. It would be nice if it showed up here https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/version-specific/. It might be possible to get it by looking at the git history for when this line changed over time https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/e7564c354d5f37598ad2bbe434f15634fdf24aa8/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/General.php#L29

Comment: There is a table of historic php and civi versions here: https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#php-version